# Vertical scroll bar is missing even though the grid has scrollbar property set to true

Tags: winforms

I have a datagrid whose scroll bar property is set to both. But when i open it in my screen size 18 inch the vertical scroll bar doesn't appear. It appears when i resize the width of the window.How can i see the vertical scroll bar when it is loaded in my screen?

Comment: The scrollbars only appear when your data is wider or higher than your DataGridView.

Comment: How can we  resolve the issue?

Comment: Why would you show them even when they are not needed?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom DGV which overrides the automatic behavior of when to show or not to show the vertical scrollbar

```
public class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public CustomDataGridView() : base()
    {
        VerticalScrollBar.Visible = true;
        VerticalScrollBar.VisibleChanged += VerticalScrollBar_VisibleChanged;
    }

    private void VerticalScrollBar_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!VerticalScrollBar.Visible)
        {
            int width = VerticalScrollBar.Width;
            VerticalScrollBar.Location =
                new Point(ClientRectangle.Width - width, 1);
            VerticalScrollBar.Size =
                new Size(width, ClientRectangle.Height - 1 - this.HorizontalScrollBar.Height);
            VerticalScrollBar.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

This was taken from this source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/516851de-ac00-4442-b846-44734dcbd7f5/always-display-vertical-scrollbar-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols